# HTML <span> and svg element are not inline

Tags: html, css, svg, inline

My current situation is a fieldset that is inline with another one on my page.
The fieldset this post is about contains a svg circle and some text.

My goal is to have both of these inline to each other, with the fieldset adapting in size because i want to change the given `<span>`/`<p>` text and the color of the circle later on based on a function that returns either true or false.

My current code is this:

```html
<div>
  <fieldset class="fieldset-auto-width">
    <legend>some legend</legend>
    <div>
      <svg height="32" width="32"><circle id="circle" cx="16" cy="16" r="15" stroke="#333" stroke-width="1" fill="#ffbf00"/></svg>
    </div>
    <span>some text</span>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

[JS-Fiddle to my code with CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/L70oupcp/2/)

At this point i am not even sure if the second div that wraps the svg element is needed, because im trying to get it right for about half an hour now. The nested dif was there because i tried to force a maximum size to the svg element because of the unwanted space it took, even with `style="display: block"`

Now i want my svg circle and my `<span>` inline.

The reason why i am currently using `<span>` and not `<p>` is because there is too much unwanted space below the svg, which is not as critical when using `<span>` instead of `<p>`.

Edit: wrong jsfiddle link

Comment: Do you want this? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Muhammad_Usman/L70oupcp/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. `div` is a block element. So, you have to make it inline-block. `vertical-align: middle` sets the vertical alignment of an element

```html
<div>
 <fieldset class="fieldset-auto-width" >
  <legend>some legend</legend>
   <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle">
    <svg height="32" width="32">
     <circle id="circle" cx="16" cy="16" r="15" stroke="#333" stroke-width="1" fill="#ffbf00"/>
    </svg>
   </div>  
  <span>some text</span>
 </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand your question entirely but your span element is not in the same container as the SVG. Since you've set your SVG element to display inline-block, this has no effect to your span.

To align these two vertically, you can use vertical-align: middle on both your elements (svg and span) and set your SVG to display:inline-block

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/L70oupcp/5/

```
      <div>
        <svg height="32" width="32">
           <circle id="circle" cx="16" cy="16" r="15" stroke="#333" stroke-width="1" fill="#ffbf00"/>
        </svg>
        <span>some text</span>
      </div>
```

Comment: im feeling very stupid now. You totally understood my question. I added this div because i had the spacing problem earlier and tried to "cut" the svg by limiting the div in height and width - which did not work btw- and i did not realize that this was the root of my second problem, thank you very much! Is there a way to center my text vertically so it is on the same hieght as the center point of the circle?

Comment: No problem, everyone can miss sometimes. Here is an updated fiddle with aligned items : https://jsfiddle.net/L70oupcp/5/ If this is the expected result, please mark this answer as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A `<div>` is `display: block` by default.

If you want the content of the div and the element following the div to be inline with each other … don't put a div there.

```html
<div>
 <fieldset class="fieldset-auto-width" >
  <legend>some legend</legend>
    <svg height="32" width="32">
     <circle id="circle" cx="16" cy="16" r="15" stroke="#333" stroke-width="1" fill="#ffbf00"/>
    </svg>
  <span>some text</span>
 </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much, the div was because i had spacing trouble and i read somewhere that i just put a div around and limit the size of the div. which did not work.|| is it possible to lift the span text up, so that it centers with the center of the circle?